# RaphaelJS: changing variable attributes if found from page hash

Tags: javascript, hash, raphael

Say I have `var mycircle = paper.circle(0, 0, 20).attr({stroke: "#ff0000"});`

Now by default when someone goes to my page at `www.url.com/index.html` they get this circle with the red stroke.

However, what if I wanted 
the circle stroke to change if a #hash was defined when browsing, e.g. 
a selection was made and you wanted to link it to someone. Say someone 
browses to `www.url.com/index.html#mycircle` now.

With: `var hash = window.location.hash.substr(1)` I can make the variable hash return "mycircle".

However, by doing 
`hash.attr({stroke: "#0000ff"});` the stroke colour wont change to blue! Is there a way around this so I could change the stroke of the circle like so?

// EDIT

I have set up my circles like so:

```
var name1 = paper.circle(....);
name1.node.id = "name1";
name1.node.name = "Name";

var name2 = paper.circle(....);
name2.node.id = "name2";
name2.node.name = "Another Name";
```

And so on. Then I have combined them into a set:

```
nodes = paper.set();
nodes.push(name1, name2, name3, name4....);
```

I then use `nodes.hover(function() { });` and `nodes.click(function() { });` to define actions. The `name.node.id` is used for loading the right info page into a div while the `name.node.name` appears above the node when the user hovers over it.

I tried reorganizing my nodes as suggested:

```
var mapObjects = {};

mapObjects['name1'] = paper.circle(....);
mapObjects['name1'].node.id = "name1";
mapObjects['name1'].node.name = "Name";

mapObjects['name2'] = paper.circle(....);
mapObjects['name2'].node.id = "name1";
mapObjects['name2'].node.name = "Another Name";
```

I then tried to use the functions like I did before by simply changing nodes into mapObjects `mapObjects.hover(function() { });` same with click. These didn't work anymore! The hash technique worked tho so that's a step to the right direction. How do I get my hover and click functions working now?

Comment: Try `mapObjects['name1'] = name1;` instead of `mapObjects['name1'] = paper.circle(....); ...`. When you call `paper.circle` it creates a new circle. That isn't what you want because you have already created them.

Comment: Ok this works if I add the hash variable and myObjects[hash].attr commands at the very end of the script. Otherwise it breaks the script if no hash is added or if the #hash doesn't exist in the mapObjects array. Is this a bad thing? I assume the script still breaks but as long as they are the very last elements does it matter?

Comment: I tried adding jQuery if($.inArray(hash, mapObjects) but it didn't help. It would be useful to get this working as I have to assign the hash as the value for the variable "lastCircle" and if no circle is selected lastCircle = null;

Comment: Oh well I guess it's enough as it seems to work when it's at the end of the script. Thanks for all your help Marian!

Comment: Eh this is a bit beyond me as a beginner but things started working when I simply created another array, var anotherArray = ["name1", "name2", "name....]; and then tested hash against this with the forementioned $.inArray(hash, anotherArray)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The eval would help, but it would be very vulnerable. The better way is to remember the circle in associative array:

```
var objects = {};
objects['mycircle'] = paper.circle(0, 0, 20).attr({stroke: "#ff0000"});
objects[hash].attr({stroke: "#0000ff"});
```

Comment: So if I would have 40 different circles I'd list them similarly

    objects['mycircle1'] = ...
    objects['mycircle2'] = ...

and so on with the hash one last? All the circles would have the same stroke, it's just for highlighting the selection.

Comment: Ok I see this works at least on the basic level. My script is quite complex so I'll try to work it with this principal and return to you in a bit. Thank you Marian!

Comment: While all the objects will be unique instances (with the same stroke), it would highlight just one.

Comment: I've added more information to the original message as I couldn't get everything working.